# ODI 12.2.1 - How to get Specific table names for C$ Loading table during runtime

Tags: xml, oracle, data-migration, oracle-data-integrator

I have migrated a ODI project from ODI 11.1.1.7 to 12.2.1 using ODI migration tool.

The Source is XML file and Target is Oracle 12c Database.

In the migrated project, I could see some of the Interfaces are changed drastically.

There are additional object which are created.
Default_DS_AP and Default_DS1_AP objects are created in Target Group of Interface.
Looks like this is used to Load the data from Source to Target object using LKM SQL to Oracle.

But during migration I could see that when C$ tables are created, it is getting created with some unique table names that DONT match the target table.

For some of the interface where i have only 1 DEAFULT_DS_AP object , I am able to see C$ Loading object created with proper target table name.

But , where 2 DEFAULT_DS objects are present in Physical tab of Interface, Loading tables are created with C$_0DEFAULT_DS , C$_0DEFAULT_DS1..

HOW can I get proper table names like C$_0ADDNUMEBRS  where ADDNUMBERS is my table name?

Also, The Loading tables are not created correctly , it is jumbled up and hence IKM query is not getting executed properly.

any help on this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading from 11g to 12c, ODI will use datasets in all your mappings. This is why you see this additional Default_DS_AP and Default_DS1_AP nodes in the physical design. You can however remove these datasets and use the flow paradigm instead (see http://www.rittmanmead.com/2015/04/di-tips-odi-convert-to-flow/).

This might not solve your problems with the target table name though. With 12c, ODI now allows to have more than one target in a mapping. This means that the target table name can not be used anymore as a temporary name in all the cases. Instead, ODI uses the name of the last component before the data transport in the LKM steps which creates the C$_ tables It's possible to change that to get back to the previous behavior but it requires a bit of changes in each mapping (that can be automated in Groovy) or in the KMs. You will find more details in [this blog post](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2016/05/ditips-odi12c-table-names/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has helped me to resolve the issue to much extent.